# Showing data in input using ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to get some data from db. Now I can get the data at the backend. But the only problem is I just cannot show that in the input below. I also write some code but that's not working. Here is my code. The ajax part is working but not the javascrpit. Help me if you can :)

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('select[name="class_id"]').on('change',function() {
        var ClassID = jQuery(this).val();
        if (ClassID) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '/ajaxFee/' + ClassID,
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    jQuery('input[name="class_fee"]').empty();
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key,value) {
                        $('input[name="class_fee"]').append(
                          '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>'
                        );
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('input[name="class_fee"]').empty();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please avoid mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. I edited the white-space and indentation for you this time.

Comment: Hi, are you here?

Comment: yes sir i am here

Comment: let chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193158/laravel-issues

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the mistake is much simpler than you think :)

Change this:

```
$('input[name="class_fee"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
```

to this:

```
$('select[name="class_fee"]').empty();
$('select[name="class_fee"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
```

You want to append options to a select element, not to an input. And change all the references.

-- EDIT

You should have an element in your page like this:

```
<select name="class_fee"></select>
```

You cannot append `option` to an `input` element.

Comment: And do you have an HTML element on the page `<select name="class_fee"></select>`?

Comment: No I have input type text for class_fee that's why i had changed the select to input in my javascript

Comment: You cannot append options to an input element. So change that.

Comment: Please you can update your answer. So that way I can see my mistake

Comment: @HasnainKahn make sure that the accepted answer is really what you need, because you use `each` which means you are iterating over a collection which will set your input element value to the last item from the collection. You probably test with a collection of one item and it works now, but if you have more items, it will show just the last one.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your getting 'fee' for selected class and data length is 1

Replace

```
$('input[name="class_fee"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
```

to

```
$('input[name="class_fee"]').val(value)
```

Comment: @Hasnain Kahn Please let me know what is wrong in my answer.I  provided answer before Sahil